# Copying Character Arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

I have an array of size 81 being passed into the result parameter but that array has not been modified by the time this program ends. For example, the input would be `"   city    "` and the result string should be `"city"`. Am I incorrectly copying characters somewhere?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "textmanipulation.h"

static int getLength(const char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = 1;
    while (str[i+1] != '\0') {
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    return count;
}

void remove_spaces(const char *source, int *status, char *result) {
    int first = 0;
    int last;
    int i;
    int length = getLength(source);
    if (source[0] == '\0' || source == NULL) {
        *status = FAILURE;
    } else {
        printf("LENGTH: %d\n", length);
        *status = SUCCESS;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (source[i] != ' ') {
                first = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        last = first;
        printf("FIRST: %d\n" , first);
        for (i = first; i < length; i++) {
            if (source[i] == ' ') {
                last = i - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (i = first; i <= last; i++) {
            result[i] = source[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, one thing, you should probably do the null-check, ' source == NULL', before you try an dereference it with 'source[0] == '\0'.

Comment: What happens when you run it?  'printf("LENGTH: %d\n", length);' - well, what does it printf out?  Is the length right?  You need to tell us such things!  You have obviously tested it, so why withhold what you found out?

Comment: Did you run it under a debugger?  If not, why not?

Comment: LENGTH: prints out 11, like it should. When I check length of result, which is initialized in my test, it comes out to be 0

Comment: Strings can have a length of zero; your code would not detect that reliably.  You only need one of `i` and `count` — in fact, `count` is redundant and wrong.  The loop condition should be `str[i] != '\0'` and you should lose `count`, returning `i` at the end of the function.

Comment: @Jenny If there is no reason you cannot use standard functions to remove the leading/trailing spaces, then you could simply do `char *remove_spaces (const char *source, char *result) { if (sscanf (source, "%s", result) == 1) return result; else return NULL; }` and avoid all the index gymnastics.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
   last = first;
    printf("FIRST: %d\n" , first);
    for(i= first; i< length; i++){
        if(source[i] == ' '){
          last = i-1;
          break;
        }
    }
```

What happens if there are no spaces?  Nothing.  last==first.  So, if your first character is not a space, first = 0.  And if no spaces are encountered, last = first.  This means that last = first = 0.

And so:

```
    for(i=first; i<= last; i++){
      result[i] = source[i];
```

...does nothing but copy the first char.  Change the code to:

```
   last = first;
    printf("FIRST: %d\n" , first);
    for(i= first; i< length; i++){
        if(source[i] != ' '){
          last = i;
        }
        else break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to trim the string ( trimming a string means removing the white spaces from the begging and the end of a string for example `s ="  Hello   World ";`
the result would be "Hello   World")
so your mistake is that you remove just the first white space `"  Hello World"`
would be `" Hello World"`
so you have to do this to specify the first character of the result string

```
//remove the white spaces from the begging of the string 
    int i =0 ;
    while( i < length && source[i] == ' ') i++;
    int first = i ;
    //remove the white spaces from the end of the string 
    i = length -1 ;
   while( i >= 0 && source[i] == ' ') i--; 
   int end = i ; 
   int j =0 ; 
   for( i = first ; i <= end ; i ++ ) result[j++] = source[i]; 
   result[j] = '\0';
```

Otherwise if you are tying to remove all the white spaces in the string you can simply do so :

```
int i = 0 , j =0 ; 
for(i =0 ; i < length ; i ++ ) { 
   if(source[i] != ' ' ) result[j++] = source[i]; 
}
result[j] = '\0';
```

and I hope that was useful for you

Answer (score 0):

The function below, `trimmer()`, trims leading and trailing while spaces from a character string. I will add it into [zString](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString) code :)

Function uses a check variable (`int in_word`) to decide whether it is inside a word or not.
Copies all characters, includeing white-spaces to the destination. Saves the index of the last "non-white space" character and terminates the string by using this index value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *trimmer(char *str){
    char *src=str;  /* save the original pointer */
    char *dst=str;  /* result */
    int in_word=0;  /* logical check */
    int index=0;    /* index of the last non-space char*/

    while (*src)
        if(*src!=' '){
         /* Found a word */
            in_word = 1;
            *dst++ = *src++;  /* make the assignment first
                               * then increment
                               */
        } else if (*src==' ' && in_word==0) {
         /* Already going through a series of white-spaces */
            in_word=0;
            ++src;
        } else if (*src==' ' && in_word==1) {
         /* End of a word, dont mind copying white-spaces here */
            in_word=0;
            *dst++ = *src++;
            index = dst-str; /* save the location of the last char*/
        }

    /* terminate the string */
    *(str+index)='\0';

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char s[]="     Hello world!     ";
    printf("%s\n",trimmer(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Output of theis code is

```
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenny, I'm not sure if you are required to approach the problem as you have from an assignment standpoint, but if not, there are several things that could make your approach a bit easier.

The first being, you are dealing with a *nul-terminated* string. So for the purpose of manipulating any of the characters within the string, there is no need to compute an independent *length*. You can simply iterate over the characters in the string (with either an *index* or a *pointer* until the *nul-terminating* character is reached. That itself eliminates the need for a separate `getlength` function.

Next, when you look at `strlen`, it returns type `size_t` instead of type `int`. `size_t` is simply limited to the positive values of type `int`, but it makes more sense when working with a length, because you cannot have a *negative* number of characters. Also, by choosing the appropriate type, you make your `getlength` function compatible with all the standard library function that expect to take a `size_t` number of characters (without having to *cast*).

A similar *type* (and parameter) mismatch occurs in your `remove_spaces` function. When dealing with character string manipulation functions, they generally return a pointer to `char *` to make the result of the function assignable, or useable directly in any function that takes a pointer. (e.g. `printf ("reversed string : %s\n", remove_spaces (old_string, new_string));`)

While it is apparent you pass the pointer `int *status` as a way of making indicating *success/failure* back in the calling function, success or failure when dealing with character strings is generally indicated by either the return of a valid `char *` string, or `NULL` otherwise. That is another primary argument for making `remove_spaces` type `char *` instead of `void`. Additionally, returning a pointer to a valid string, or `NULL` is all you need to indicate success/failure of the function, thus eliminating the need for `int *status` entirely.

Approaching `remove_spaces` in that manner, you can then decide whether you want to implement it with pointers and indexes or whether you want to rely on one or more of the standard library functions. For instance, depending on the length of input you are taking, you may want a completely different approach.

If your input string is limited to a *single-word*, look at the standard function `sscanf`, along with the `%s` *format-specifier*. When `%s` is used to parse a *one-word* string, it *ignores leading whitespace* and stops conversion when the *first trialing whitespace* is encountered. Putting the pieces together to use `sscanf` with `remove_spaces` in this case, you could do something simple like

```
char *remove_spaces_word (const char *source, char *result)
{
    if (sscanf (source, "%s", result) == 1)
        return result;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Of course you are likely to have input containing many words. When working with character strings, there are times when advancing a pointer over each character in the string is much less work than trying to access each character using an *array-index*. It also eliminates keeping track of additions and subtractions to an index. You may also find that pointers are a more natural way of working with characters in a string.

To handle removing whitespace from any string, regardless of the number of words involved, an approach using pointers rather than indexes could look something like:

```
char *remove_spaces (const char *s, char *r)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return NULL;             /* validaate source str      */
    char *p = r;                            /* pointer to result         */
    *r = 0;                                 /* initialize as empty str   */
    while (isspace (*s))  s++;              /* skip leading whitespace   */
    for (; *s; s++, p++) *p = *s;           /* fill r with s to end      */
    *p = 0;                                 /* nul-terminate r           */
    while (p > s && isspace (*--p)) *p = 0; /* overwrite spaces from end */

    return r;
}
```

You can see how it works. If `s` is *empty* or `NULL`, `NULL` is returned. Then pointer `p` is assigned the address of `r` (the result). The `isspace` function (in `ctype.h`) is used to skip over all leading spaces until the first *non-space* character is found (`s` not points to the first character you want to keep). The *entire* remainder of `s` (including all the trailing spaces) is then copied to `r` and `r` is *nul-terminated*. Finally, `r` is positively *nul-terminated* and `p` is then used to backtrack from the end overwriting all trailing spaces with the *nul-terminating* character `0`.

Note: there are probably 20 more different ways to implement a function like this. The functions of `strchr`, `strrchr`, `strpbrk`, `strspn`, `strcspn` and the like can all be used to help locate a pointer at the beginning or end of characters within a string. There is no one "right-way" to approach this problem. You approach was fine, it was just somewhat the long-way-around-the-bush, and generally the longer and more involved an approach is, the more opportunity there is for error.

Look over all the answers here and look at the different approaches. Compare/contrast each of them. Look at the other functions available and try writing your function as many different ways as you desire. With each way try and consider all the different ways a user could screw-up the input and try and craft a solution that covers all cases. (there will always be a corner-case or two you don't consider, so try and test as many input combinations as you can think of) There is no substitute or better way to get familiar with an aspect of C than just trying different approaches out. In the end, pick the one that works best for your situation. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an array of size 81 being passed into the result parameter but
>   that array has not been modified by the time this program ends.

This is not true; see below.

> Am I incorrectly copying characters somewhere?

Indeed you are. With your example source    `city`    , `first` is 3 and `last` 6 at the copy loop

```
        for (i = first; i <= last; i++) {
            result[i] = source[i];
        }
```

- so you're copying `city` to `result[3]` thru `result[6]`. When you *check the length of `result`*, which as you say *is initialized* (to `\0`s, I presume), *it comes out to be 0* because `result[0]` is `\0`.

Surely you meant to copy `city` to `result` starting from `result[0]`, which could be done with

```
        for (i = first; i <= last; i++) result[i-first] = source[i];
```